# How to resize an image by adding extra pixels using matlab

Tags: image, matlab, resize, pixel

I would like to resize a 512X512 image into 363X762 image which will be larger than the original image(of size 512X512). Those extra pixel values must be different values in the range of 0-255. 
I tried the following code:

```
I=imread('photo.jpg'); %photo.jpg is a 512X512 image
B=zeros(363,726);
sizeOfMatrixB=size(B);
display(sizeOfMatrixB);
B(1:262144)=I(1:262144);
imshow(B);
B(262155:263538)=0;
```

But I think this is a lengthy one and the output is also not as desired. Could anyone suggest me with a better piece of code to perform this. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the code you have is actually pretty close to ideal except that you have a  lot of hard-coded values in there. Those should really be computed on the fly. We can do that using `numel` to count the number of elements in `B`.

```
B = zeros(363, 726);

%// Assign the first 262144 elements of B to the values in I
%// all of the rest will remain as 0
B(1:numel(I)) = I;
```

This flexibility is important and the importance is actually demonstrated via the typo in your last line:

```
B(262155:263538)=0;

%// Should be
B(262144:263538)=0;
```

Also, you don't need these extra assignments to zero at the end because you initialize the matrix to be all zeros in the first place.

**A Side Note**

It looks like you are spreading the original image data for each column across multiple columns. I'm guessing this isn't what you want. You probably only want to grab the *first 363* rows of `I` to be placed into `B`. You can do that this way:

```
B = zeros(363, 726);
B(1:size(B, 1), 1:size(I, 2)) = I(1:size(B, 1), :);
```

**Update**

If you want the other values to be something *other* than zero, you can initialize your matrix to be *that value* instead.

```
value = 2;
B = zeros(363, 726) + value;
B(1:numel(I)) = I;
```

If you want them to be random integers between 0 and 255, use `randi` to initialize the matrix.

```
B = randi([0 255], 363, 726);
B(1:numel(I)) = I;
```

Comment: Oh thanks @suever! But how about changing those extra pixels to some other values in the range 0-255 rather than simply zero. Could you please try that too.

Comment: @lakshmisai Updated with an example of how to do that.

Comment: @sueverCan I have some different random values assignment instead of a single value for all the extra pixels? Anyway I have checked it just now. It's working perfect in the way I needed. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: @lakshmisai Do you want truly random data? If so, initialize to `rand(363, 726)`. If that's not what you want please elaborate

Comment: @lakshmisai It would be much easier if you just added all of your requirements to your question rather than stringing them out one by one. That's kind of unfair to people who are giving up their time to help you.

Comment: @suever Yeah I need to fill those extra pixel values with random integers but the range of random integers must be confined to 0-255

Comment: @lakshmisai See update at the end. You will want to use `randi`

Comment: Oh sorry for that @beaker I thought that my question was complete until I got answers from Suever. I'll do that thing you said. Thanks

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot once again @Suever. You made my task much simpler. Have a good day.