# How to remove last n elements of a matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a matrix of order `363 X 726`. Now I wanted to remove last 1394 elements in column-major format so that I can rearrange it into `512 X 512` matrix using MATLAB. Simply put, I want to perform the reversal of the operations seen in my previous question: [How to resize an image by adding extra pixels using matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484804/how-to-resize-an-image-by-adding-extra-pixels-using-matlab).  How can I do this in MATLAB?

Comment: How are you determining which 1394 elements to remove? Row-major? Column-major? Random? Arbitrary? What if the information is important?

Comment: Not a particular row or column but the last 1394 elements in the matrix, why because (363*726=263538) - (512*512=262144) = 1394. So I wanted to remove last 1394 elements to match the matrix dimensions.That matrix pertains to an image,So if I remove the random elements, information would be lost.Certainly I don't need those last elements because they are manually added for some operation by myself.@excaza

Comment: "last" does not have a specific meaning for arrays with more than one dimension, hence the question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36484804/how-to-resize-an-image-by-adding-extra-pixels-using-matlab please refer the above link to get a clear picture of what I am trying to tell. I just want the reverse operation to be done.

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @excaza The accessing is in column-major if I am understanding the previous post.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your matrix you want to operate on is called `B`, you could also just do `B = reshape(B(1:512*512), 512, 512);`. No need for a temporary variable and the removal of the last 1394 elements is implicit with the indexing.

Comment: @sai No problem. Whenever you're ready, remember to accept either one of our answers to let the community know you no longer need help.  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

```
A = rand(363,726);        % matrix of random elements with size 363x726 
A(end-1393:end)=[] ;     % removing last 1394 elements
A = reshape(A,[512 512]); % Rearranging it into 512 rows and 512 columns
```

Comment: Thanks @Sardar_Usama